# Server displays old version of site

Tags: zend-framework, smarty

Good day to all.

I have a site (created with zend framework and smarty) hosted on a virtual machine (vmware) with centOS 5.2. Everything worked fine for about 2 month, but a problem occurred now. I am trying to modify some .tpl files and after I save and upload on server (the one on the virtual machine) the server gives me the old version of the page.

Already cleared cache, change browser, etc... is not browser related.
I tried on different computers and all have the same result.

I also checked the uploaded file and it is the new one.

Caching is disabled.

If I delete the file I get the error (what is normal). If I delete the file then upload the new file I still get the old version.

I deleted everything inside the file (directly on the uploaded file - ftp) I still get the old version.

I don't have any other ideas so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart webserver ? - Check to ensure all caches deleted (Zend and Smarty)
Smarty does have a cache setting too, maybe try turning that off

Comment: You were right, i only deactivated zend caching, didn't know that smarty has one also and another collegue avtivated it. Thank you.