# php, zend. smarty - Server displays old version of site

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching, smarty

This is related to post:
[Server displays old version of site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647329/server-displays-old-version-of-site)

To repeat the question:

Good day to all.

I have a site (created with zend framework and smarty) hosted on a virtual machine (vmware) with centOS 5.2. Everything worked fine for about 2 month, but a problem occurred now. I am trying to modify some .tpl files and after I save and upload on server (the one on the virtual machine) the server gives me the old version of the page.

Already cleared cache, change browser, etc... is not browser related. I tried on different computers and all have the same result.

I also checked the uploaded file and it is the new one.

If I delete the file I get the error (what is normal). If I delete the file then upload the new file I still get the old version.

I i delete everything inside the file (directly on the uploaded file - ftp) I still get the old version.

When I first ask this I got the suggestion to disable smarty caching, did it and worked... but it seems it was a coincidence and now it happens again (but the fix doesn't work :( ).

Comment: Do you clear the smarty compiled directory when you publish?

Comment: I kind of cleared all cached data. Deleted all from the cache directory (think the templates_c where the smarty generated files). So... since I only have the sources now should be all right. But to answer your question: I don't know what was deleted and not when project was published first time (I was not working here and the guy left).

Comment: Silly question - please forgive me, but are you uploading in the correct directory? If you put an echo `'hello!'; exit;` on the index. Does it show?

Comment: Trust me I upload the correct directory :)). And if I modify the index.php with the echo I see the hello. Also i've been modifying this files for months (and worked fine with the one exception when I posted the problem first time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the FTP update the timestsamp properly?

We've had problems when deploying where our changed files don't get their modified timestamps updated which causes our opcode caching on the server to not read the new files.

If you have access, try stop/starting the service and see if that fixes the issue.

#### Edit: Comment Response

I assume you mean the cache and/or the compiled files that Smarty creates. Smarty compiles the templates into PHP, then if it's a static page, it can cache the resulting HTML. The opcode caching (typically APC on Apache) caches compile bytecode that is generated from the source files and is typically stored in memory [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator).

Comment: +1, I've had this issue as well. You can try `touch /path/to/file.tpl` on the server as well to update the timestamp, and check the settings in your optcode cache (if you are using one), and/or try restarting Apache to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: First lead I got till now... I'm gonna try it. But wouldn't deleting the cache be a fix? I deleted the cache and same problem.

Comment: Updated answer with explanation of different caches involved.